# transform: scale... rendering font poorly in MS operating systems

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

When animating font with `transform: scale(1.05)` the font renders poorly when using OS's from MicroSoft (Win8.1 and Win10). This seems to happen in all the browsers I have checked (IE8, IE11, MSEdge and Chrome).

This is not a problem when using macOS Sierra and all other browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera, FireFox). I had a similar problem in OSX and Safari which I fixed using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` but I am unable to find a solution to my Microsoft font rendering problem.

I have set up an example to demonstrate this: [see example](https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/3532/)

Comment: why don't you just increase `font-size` on `hover` ?

Comment: In my experiment with your jsfiddle standard font is okay.

Comment: Using font-size is something I have considered, however it does introduce other problems for my as in the containers themselves scale and change the layout of my application. @artgb did you try it in IE while using windows?

Comment: Yes, I tried in windows firefox and IE with Arial font and working well

Comment: I think  widows not provide  good Gorditas font information.

Comment: I was hoping to get this to work with my selected google font. Do I need to implement this with font-size to get it to work in windows?

Comment: It works fine in Firefox/Win btw. The problem for some of the browsers is that they calculate the transform into a font-size instead of applying transform to the existing points of the font at that size. And since fonts can have different hinting information for each size to optimize anti-aliasing etc., the font may change appearance. The only workaround is to render the text as bitmap (using canvas) and scale that (with all its drawback as well as lack of support in IE8).

Comment: (you can try to use a SVG font too, or use a library to extract font paths and convert those to SVG - but again, it will exclude older browsers and now it's going downhill performance and maintenance wise :) ).

Comment: Thank you @K3N really good information. I will look into your suggested solutions to see which works better and update this question. 

Thanks :)